# How to execute a java class from python in Heroku

Tags: java, python, heroku, classpath

I'm building an Heroku app based on Python, but I need to call a Java Class at a certain point of the python code, using subprocess:

```
def execute_java(java_file, arg0, arg1):
    java_class,ext = os.path.splitext(java_file)
    cmd = ['java', java_class, arg0, arg1]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
```

On my local machine, I can do that without any problem, but on Heroku, the error is always the same:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ClassName

My procfile is the following: 
`web: java -cp logic/classes/:logic/dependency/* ClassName`

Because the java class is located in the folder called 'logic' of the project.

Useful information:

1. The Java `buildpack` is already installed and located at heroku/jvm
2. The java class has not any package, it is just a .class file with the main method and another method.

Comment: How does the python code get executed? It seems the `Procfile` should contain a python command?

Comment: the app is a telegram bot, the procfile line for the python code is: web: python3 bot.py ${8443}

Comment: You can only have one web command

Comment: That's not true: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format

Comment: It’s not stated very explicitly in the doc but you definitely can only have one web process type (or any process type name)

Comment: Ok, but this means that I cannot set the classpath and execute a java class in python code?